# How many hours does it take to backup the PS3 internal drive if it is 1.0 TB

Tags: ps3, hardware, hard-drive

How long or how much time does it take for a PS3 to backup a 1 TB internal drive to a USB external drive using the official [Backup Utility](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps3/current/settings/backuputility.html)?

Answer (score -2):

If the PS3 internal drive was filled with about 40% game saves & game data, and about 55% Video data (Torne for Japan, DVR recordings), or in other words, 948GB possible and 20GB available, then the estimation given by the Backup Utility was 28 hours. The actual time was **fill in the blank**.

- My PS3 was a "Slim [model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayStation_3_models)" CECH-3000A (2011/11) with 4.55 (2014/02) system firmware.
- My internal hard drive was **fill in the blank**
- My external hard drive was a Western Digital Caviar Green 2.0 TB (not Advanced Format) in an off the shelf hard disk enclosure kit.
- The latter was connected via a daisy-chain of two USB 2.0 hubs.